# Why am I getting an NPE in ValueOfCopyOfInterpreter when inserting a BLOB?

Tags: oracle, nullpointerexception, orbeon

To see the issue:

1. Create a table in Oracle with:

   ```
   create table ut_table_ut_service_pj (
      PATH VARCHAR(80),
      BINARY BLOB
   );
   ```
2. Paste the following pipeline in the XPL sandbox, you can access on `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/sandbox-transformations/xpl/`, replacing the database URI, username, and password as appropriate on your system:

   ```
   <p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
             xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
             xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
             xmlns:odt="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/datatypes"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">

       <p:processor name="oxf:url-generator">
           <p:input name="config">
               <config>
                   <url>test.pdf</url>
                   <mode>binary</mode>
               </config>
           </p:input>
           <p:output name="data" id="document"/>
       </p:processor>

       <p:processor name="oxf:sql">
           <p:input name="datasource">
               <datasource>
                   <driver-class-name>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class-name>
                   <uri>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1522/globaldb</uri>
                   <username>orbeon</username>
                   <password>password</password>
               </datasource>
           </p:input>
           <p:input name="data" href="#document"/>
           <p:input name="config">
               <sql:config>
                   <sql:connection>
                       <sql:execute>
                           <sql:update debug="write">
                               insert into ut_table_ut_service_pj
                               values('test.pdf',
                               <sql:param select="/*"
                                          type="xs:base64Binary" sql-type="blob"/>
                               )
                           </sql:update>
                       </sql:execute>
                   </sql:connection>
               </sql:config>
           </p:input>
       </p:processor>

   </p:config>
   ```

This leads to the following exception:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.interpreters.ValueOfCo|<init>                        |ValueOfCopyOfInterpreter.java |  48|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$Interpret|addAllDefaultElementHandlers  |SQLProcessor.java             | 476|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.interpreters.ConfigInt|start                         |ConfigInterpreter.java        |  32|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$Interpret|startElement                  |SQLProcessor.java             | 503|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$RootInter|startElement                  |SQLProcessor.java             | 280|
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is a [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/349). This is [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/dda2cfad55a5ee1ed89371b7a36f8421c8e53569) as of 2012-07-03.

- In the `ValueOfCopyOfInterpreter`, `interpreterContext.getCurrentNode()` is null.

  - This `SQLProcessorInterpreterContext` is created in the constructor for `RootInterpreter`.
  - The first node in the interpreter context `currentNodes` is added in `SQLProcessorInterpreterContext.setInput()`, which is called with `null` by `RootInterpreter`.
  - This `null` comes from `SQLProcessor.execute()` deciding that all the XPath expressions in the config (here just `/*`) can be streamed, and thus the document doesn't need to be read, which is OK.
- `ValueOfCopyOfInterpreter` uses that wrapper to:

  - Evaluate `string(.)` on a list (atomization), wrapping every element in the list.
  - Evaluate `string(.)` on a `Node`
- In both cases, it does indeed make sense for the wrapper to be created based `data` input document, rather than from `Dom4jUtils.createDocument()`, though I'm not sure exactly sure what the impact would be.
- Fix

  - But since at that point we must have a current node, as we are calling `XPathUtils.selectObjectValue()` passing that current node, it seems that it makes sense to delay the creation of the wrapper until that point.
  - Still keep the `wrapper` as object attribute, so we don't unnecessarily re-create wrappers.

The next error is: `Invalid sql-type attribute: blob`, due to another [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/350). This is [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/9eb052228befc72607e45853a89b2a16eff5b86d) as of 2012-07-03.

- This is triggered by `<sql:param select="/*" type="xs:base64Binary" sql-type="blob"/>`.
- In `QueryInterpreter`, if the type is `xs:anyURI`, then we use the same technique for both BLOB and CLOB.
- But if the type is `xs:base64Binary`, we through an exception if the type is BLOB.

  - BTW, this is what is being used when storing files by the MySQL and Oracle persistence layers.
- So it seems reasonable to do the same when the type is `xs:base64Binary`.